# Como instalar e usar cordova-plugin-term-printer no IONIC 2

Tags: ionic2, impressora, cordova-plugin, ionic3

Estou com dificuldades em instalar este plugin Cordova no IONIC 2
"cordova-plugin-term-printer" por este não ser um plugin nativo fiquei limitado.
Acreditem pesquisei a mais de 7 dias e vendo e revendo as mesmas páginas de soluções que nunca funcionam.

Gostaria de instalar o plugin e efetuar impressão em minha impressora térmica MTP-3 Printer. Caso contrário um sugestão para pesquisa ou até outro plugin.